# Netezza : Update error : cross database connection not supported for this type of command

Tags: netezza

I am trying to update a table in Netezza getting below error

"Update table table1
set col1 = val1
where col2 = "xx"

I am getting below error :
"Netezza : cross database connection not supported for this type of command "

what could be the possible reason

Answer (score 0):

You need to ‘switch’ to the database where the ‘table1’ is located. Many people connect to the SYSTEM database, but it’s a bad idea to put your tables/views there. In this example, I assume that table1 is in the EDW database:

```
Set catalog EDW
;
Update table table1 set col1 = val1 where col2 = ‘xx’
;
```

I hope that makes sense to you?

Comment: Yes similar suggestion i  found on google but didnt work
Finally i selected database from the TOP DROPDOWN list in sql developer /aginity
Then it query executed

Comment: That will work as well. I aginity you need to execute both statements as one by selecting the entire text and press F5 ...